# Issue with keyboard keys on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am facing issues from the past several days on ubuntu only. My keyboard keys got disabled automatically and after a few secs, it got enabled then disabled then enabled automatically. Only ctrl, alt, tab, and numeric keys above qwerty works fine every time. I am using Ubuntu for the last 3 years this problem didn't occur previously but from a few days, it is in the worst condition.
Can anyone help me with this?

System Config:

Model: Lenovo 320 15ISK

OS: All version of Ubuntu

Comment: Maybe a hardware issue. Would be good if you could try some other physical keyboard. If that doesn't help, it sounds as a bug to me which you should report as such.

Comment: Hey @GunnarHjalmarsson This issue is not occurring on Windows as I have dual boot it is occurring on ubuntu only from past few days.

Comment: One idea: You can create a new user for test purposes, log in as that user, and find out if the issue is present for the test user too.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but it didn't work.